# Link firebase account on first app launch

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make Firebase auth work with accounts that are already signed up with another provider.

So, is it possible to sign in with Facebook provider (for example) with account signed up with Google provider, without any previous signed in user ? I can not call this method as long as there is no signed in user.

```
linkWithCredential()
```

Is it possible to check if firebase account exists, using email address, ans then grab he user and link with new provider ?

Here is one of Firebase auth methods:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithFacebook(AccessToken token) {
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        RegisterActivity.this, "Facebook authentication failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();

                // Can't sign in because this account already exists with google provider
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance